# I can't understand the result of my code in Prolog Programming

Tags: prolog

I am doing Prolog Programming for my research and I got some problems.. 
First, all of my codes are below.

```
%% Lines are without period(.)

diagnosis :-
    readln(Line1),
    readln(Line2),
    readln(Line3),
    readln(Line4),
    readln(Line5),
    readln(Line6),
    readln(Line7),
    readln(Line8),
    readln(Line9),
    readln(Line10),
    write(Line1),nl,
    write(Line2),nl,
    write(Line3),nl,
    write(Line4),nl,
    write(Line5),nl,
    write(Line6),nl,
    write(Line7),nl,
    write(Line8),nl,
    write(Line9),nl,
    write(Line10),nl.
    %% (get_symptom(Line1,[man]) -> write('man!!!!!!!!!')),
    %% (get_symptom(Line2,[woman]) -> write('woman!!!!!!!!!')).
    %% if A then B else C, (A->B; C)

%% grammar
s --> np, vp.
np --> det, n.
vp --> v, np.
det --> [a].
n --> [man].
v --> [has].
n --> [woman].
n --> [fever].
n --> [runny_nose].

get_symptom(Line,N) :- s(Line,[]), member(N,Line).

member(X, [X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]) :-
    member(X,T).

%% FindSymptom(Line, [Symptom]) : - s(Line,[]), np(_, _, object,[a,
%% Symptom]), n(singular, [Symptom], []).

start :-
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
        readln(Patient), %% Here, this can be used for input of all symtoms
    diagnosis,


    hypothesis(Patient,cold,S1),
    append([cold/S1/red],[],N1),  write(S1),

    write('until...'),

    hypothesis(Patient,severe_cold,S2), write(S2),
    append([severe_cold/S2/red],N1,BarList),

    write('until...'),


        %% write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease,100),
    write(Patient),
    write(' probably has '),
    write(Disease),
    write('.'),

    test_barchart(BarList).
start :-
    write('Sorry, I don''t seem to be able to'),nl,
        write('diagnose the disease.'),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    get_symptom(Line1, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line2, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line3, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line4, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line5, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line6, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line7, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line8, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line9, [fever]);
    get_symptom(Line10, [fever]).

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    get_symptom(Line1, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line2, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line3, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line4, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line5, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line6, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line7, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line8, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line9, [runny_nose]);
    get_symptom(Line10, [runny_nose]).

hypothesis(Patient,cold,Score_Cold) :-
    (symptom(Patient,fever), Score_Cold is 100),write('!!!');
    Score_Cold is 0.

hypothesis(Patient,severe_cold,Score_Severe) :-
    ((symptom(Patient,fever), Score1 is 50);
    Score1 is 0),
    ((symptom(Patient, runny_nose), Score2 is 50);
    Score2 is 0),
    Score_Severe is Score1 + Score2.

%% hypothesis(Disease) :-
    %%(hypothesis1(Patient,cold,Score1),
    %%Score1 =:= 100 -> Disease = cold);
    %%(hypothesis2(Patient,severe_cold,Score2),
    %%Score2 =:= 100 -> Disease = severe_cold).

%% make graph for the result
:- use_module(library(pce)).
:- use_module(library(plot/barchart)).
:- use_module(library(autowin)).

test_barchart(BarList):-
    new(W, picture),
    send(W, display, new(BC, bar_chart(vertical,0,100))),
    forall(member(Name/Height/Color,
              BarList),
           (   new(B, bar(Name, Height)),
               send(B, colour(Color)),
               send(BC, append, B)
           )),
    send(W, open).
%% [X/100/red, y/150/green, z/80/blue, v/50/yellow]

%% append List
append([], L, L).
append([H|T], L2, [H|L3]):-
    append(T, L2, L3).
```

As you can see, I want to make a bar_graph from 10 input lines by extracting symptoms.. 
But when I executed this code, I got the result as below...

```
1 ?- start.
What is the patient's name? GJ
|: a man has a runny_nose
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
|: a
[a,man,has,a,runny_nose]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
[a]
!!!100until...100until...!!![GJ] probably has cold.
true
```

[image]

I only typed one symptom (runny_nose). I want to get Score for "cold" is 0, Score for "severe_cold" is 50 and BarGraph result... But What Happened? I can't find..

*****Edited****** 
I found that the problem is related to local variables (Line1, .. ,Line10) But how can I deal with? If I can make all the variables; Line1, ... , Line10 as global variables then,  I think the problem can be solved...

****Addition*****

I changed my 'start' predicate as follows...I didn't use 'diagnosis' and 'hypothesis' predicates/ But the problems is maybe.. 'get_symptoms' predicate. Is there any choice I can choose except that I don't use 'get_symptoms' and 'symptoms' predicates...? Then the code will become very coarse...

```
start :-
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
    readln(Patient), %% Here, this can be used for input of all symtom

    readln(Line1),
    readln(Line2),
    readln(Line3),
    readln(Line4),
    readln(Line5),
    readln(Line6),
    readln(Line7),
    readln(Line8),
    readln(Line9),
    readln(Line10),

    (symptom(Patient,fever,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7,Line8,Line9,Line10) -> (Cold is 80, Severe_Cold is 50)),

    (symptom(Patient,runny_nose,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7,Line8,Line9,Line10) -> Severe_Cold is Severe_Cold + 50),
    write(Severe_Cold), write(Cold),

    append([cold/Cold/red],[],N1),

    append([severe_cold/Severe_Cold/red],N1,BarList),


    %% write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.
    write(Severe_Cold),
    ((Cold =:= 100 -> Disease = cold) ; (Severe_Cold =:= 100 -> Disease = severe_cold)),
    write(Patient),
    write(' probably has '),
    write(Disease),
    write('.'),

    test_barchart(BarList).
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `append([cold/Cold/red],[],N1),`?

Comment: `Severe_Cold is Severe_Cold + 50` will always fail. Once a variable is instantiated, you can't reinstantiate it without backtracking, so this will ask if the value of `Severe_Cold` is itself plus 50, which can never be true. This requires that you study some Prolog fundamentals a bit more. :) In this case, use a new variable name, for example, `SC1 is Severe_Cold + 50`, and use `SC1` subsequently for the rest of the clause. There may be other issues, but that's one I spotted right off.

Comment: @mbratch Purpose of append([cold/Cold/red],[],N1),... is for making bargraph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349862/how-can-i-make-a-bar-chart-bar-graph-in-prolog-gui-xpce-programming Here, I asked to make a bargraph before. And I used the example code that one person gave to me.

Comment: `append([cold/Cold/red], [], N1)` just appends nothing to `[cold/Cold/red]` and instantiates `N1` with the result. So it's identical to just saying, `N1 = [cold/Cold/red]`.

Comment: @mbratch Now... I made the proper code for my purpose. Thanks!!! : ) You gave me much information.

Comment: Great! Glad it's working out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When programming in Prolog, you need to do some research into the language to understand how it works. Many Prolog beginners make the mistake of learning a couple of snippets of Prolog logic and then apply what they know of other languages to attempt to create a valid Prolog programming. However, Prolog doesn't work like other common languages at all.

Regarding variables, there are no globals. Variables are always "local" to a predicate clause. A predicate clause is one of one or more clauses that describe a predicate. For example:

```
foo(X, Y) :- (some logic including X and Y).
foo(X, Y) :- (some other logic including X and Y).
foo(X, X) :- (some other logic including X).
```

These are three clauses describing the predicate `foo/2`. The value of `X` or `Y` instantiated in one clause isn't visible to the other clauses.

If you want to instantiate a variable in one predicate and use it in another, you have to pass it as a parameter:

```
foo([1,2,3,4], L),
bar(L, X).
```

Here, `foo` might instantiate `L` using some logic and based upon the instantiated value of `[1,2,3,4]` for the first argument. Then `L` (now instantiated) is passed as the first argument to the predicate `bar`.

If you need a value to be persistent as data, you could assert it as a fact as follows:

```
foo :-
    (some logic that determines X),
    assertz(my_fact(X)),
    (more logic).

bar :-
    my_fact(X),    % Will instantiate X with what was asserted
    (some logic using X).
```

This would work, but is not a desirable approach in Prolog to "fake" global variables. Asserting items into persistent data is designed for the purpose of maintaining a Prolog database of information.

So you can see that the logic you have involving `Line1`, `Line2`, ... will not work. One clue would be that you must have received many warnings about these variables being "singleton". You need to study Prolog a bit more, then recast your logic using that knowledge.

Comment: I changed some code and edited my post above. You can see that from Addition** part... Another problems happened.. Sorry; I am really beginner for programming itself.

Comment: @GoodGJ I'm glad to be of help. A lot of Prolog beginners fall into the same traps and questions, so no worries. If you are serious about Prolog, I suggest finding a good book or tutorial to warm up to everything that makes it different.